# What's the proper way to write a rule with both int and strings in xtext?

Tags: antlr, xtext

I'm defining an Xtext grammar rule to parse a simple timestamp like YYYY-MM-DDTHH-MM-SS, but, the parser doesn't parse when I send something like `2019-01-01T08:12:14` but it does parse when I send `2019-01-01 T 08:12:14`.

I've already tried to take off every whitespace between the tokens of the rule definition but it doesn't help (and probably it shouldn't help)

The rule is:

```
Timestamp
    :
        year=INT '-' month=INT '-' day=INT 'T' hour=INT ':' minute=INT (':' second=INT)?
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

in your case making use of the `hidden()` clause should do the trick

```
Timestamp hidden()
    :
        year=INT '-' month=INT '-' day=INT 'T' hour=INT ':' minute=INT (':' second=INT)?
    ;
```

but there is another problem:

`'T' hour=INT` which requires spaces around the `T` otherwise an ID would be parsed.
you can overcome this problem using fragments

```
Timestamp
    :
        Date 'T' Time
    ;

fragment Date hidden():
    year=INT '-' month=INT '-' day=INT
;

fragment Time hidden():
    hour=INT ':' minute=INT (':' second=INT)?
;
```

but that still has the problem that it requires spaces

=> i propose to introduce a terminal rule for the whole thing (am not sure if you have conflicting ones)

```
Timestamp
    :
       ts=TS
    ;
terminal TS: INT'-'INT'-'INT'T'INT':'INT(':'INT)?;
```

Comment: Great! I created this terminal rule and almost everything worked fine, but now I've got another problem. In my DSL it is possible to do some simple math calculations and there's a conflict between timestamp and subtractions. (I think that it's due to the `-` character). So, is there some way to force a rule to be considered only if it fits entirely on it? I'm afraid that I'm not making myself clear but in my opinion, these rules shouldn't be conflicting.

Comment: either use a space in the model or try to backtrack in the lexer. am not sure if this will work in your case nor what the negative side effects may be. or digg if a jflex lexer can do better. or try to move T INT to a terminal TINT: 'T'INT and use that one + a MyID that allows combinations of ID and TINT with your original rule with hour=TINT